# Static routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have been busy trying to figure out the following problem.
I'm using redis to find the static route.

For example.
I visit the url http://www.example.com/electronics, then i get the following url back from my redis: http://www.example.com/shop/products/1

Now i would like to let Laravel "think" im visiting through the second url. So another defined route will pick it up and fires up the right controller.

This gives the right URL, but it echo's it to the browser:

```
Route::get('shop/products/{id}', 'DefaultController@getProducts');

$key = "route:" . str_replace("/", ":", Request::path());

if(Redis::hExists($key, "from_link"))
{
    $route = Redis::hMGet($key, array('from_link', 'to_link'));

    Route::get($route[0], function() use ($route)
    {
        return URL::to($route[1]);
        // return Redirect::to($route[1]);
    });
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `URL::to($route)` returns a string and will just output that to the browser. Does returning the `Redirect::to($route)` not work?

Comment: Yeah that works fine, but then the url doesn't stay electronics, which is prefered for SEO

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to achieve something with routes which you should be doing in the logic within a route. Route with wildcard for the type, check redis in the route logic. Apply the logic to return the right data rather than trying to use another route. If the other route contains logic, here is a good reason why it shouldn't.